# When was The Tale of Sinuhe first REdiscovered?

Tags: ancient-history, historiography, ancient-egypt, archaeology, egypt

I have found a [website](https://jennycarrington.tripod.com/JJSinuhe/DuplicateTexts2.html) that gives the details of all of the sources of The [Tale of Sinuhe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Story_of_Sinuhe), but I can't figure out what the actual date of discovery was for each of those sources (in order to find the earliest time of discovery) because I am not trained in history and I have trouble understanding the terminology and references.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are interested in when the primary sources we have for the story were discovered, not when the events in the story were set?

Comment: If you do a Google Scholar search by date range, the first references appear around 1906-1908. If I were going to dig further I'd check what those say.

Comment: *One* of the papyri-(Berlin 3022)-  [turned up in 1837](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/museums-static/digitalegypt/writing/library/athanasi.html), with no 'archeological context'.

Comment: @TED Yes, that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @BrianZ Thanks for the suggestion. I tried playing around with Google Scholar to get the results that you mention, but I didn't find them (probably also due to my inexperience). Can you please link your results?

Comment: @TzviK Actually here is a reference from 1894: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Egyptian_Grammar_with_Table_of_Signs_Bib/9IsBAAAAMAAJ And here are the results I was looking at earlier: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22Tale+of+Sinuhe%22&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C7&as_ylo=&as_yhi=1908